# creating two separate lists read from a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Can i please know how the data from a file can be split into two separate lists. For example,
file contains data as 1,2,3,4;5,6,7

```
my code:

for num in open('filename','r'):
  list1 = num.strip(';').split()
```

Here , i want a new list before semi colon (i.e) [1,2,3,4] and new list after semi colon (i.e) [5,6,7]

Comment: `list1 = num.split(';')[0].split(',')` `list2 = num.split(';')[1].split(',')`

Comment: Does the file have more than one line? What should happen at the line break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the final list you need to split on `","` as well (and probably `map()` the result to `int()`):

```
with open("filename") as f: 
     for line in f:
         list1, list2 = [x.split(",") for x in line.rstrip().split(";")]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain that your file only contains 2 lists, you can use a list comprehension:

```
l1, l2 = [sub.split(',') for sub in data.split(';')]
# l1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
# l2 = ['5', '6', '7']
```

More generally,

```
lists = [sub.split(',') for sub in data.split(';')]
# lists[0] = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
# lists[1] = ['5', '6', '7']
```

If integers are needed, you can use a second list comprehension:

```
lists = [[int(item) for item in sub.split(',')] for sub in data.split(';')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your file, you could simply read the whole file into a string at once and then first split by semicolon, then by comma:

```python
with open('filename', 'r') as f:  #open file
    s = f.read()   #read entire contents into string
    lists = s.split(';')  #split separate lists by semicolon delimiters
    for l in lists:  #for each list
        l = [int(x) for x in l.split(',')]  #separate the string by commas and convert to integers
```